# react: вызов диалога при выборе элемента выпадающего списка

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap, компоненты, modal

Использую React и Bootstrap:

создаю элемент выпадающего списка Dropdown:

```
// отрисовать компонент
render() {
    return (
        <Dropdown>
            <Dropdown.Toggle>...</Dropdown.Toggle>
            <Dropdown.Menu>
                <Dropdown.Item onSelect = {this.ipc__handleSelect}>...</Dropdown.Item>
            </Dropdown.Menu>
        </Dropdown>
    );
}
```

при выборе одного из элементов меню мне надо вызвать модальное окно, которое описывается моим компонентом `<MyModalDialog />`

```
// обработать выбор элемента из выпадающего списка
ipc__handleSelect = (eventKey: any, event: any) => {
    ...
}
```

подскажите, как правильнее его вызвать
пока единственное, что приходит в голову - отрисовывать элемент сразу, просто невидимым, а потом делать видимым

```
// отрисовать компонент
render() {
    return (
        <>
            <Dropdown>
                ...
            </Dropdown>
            MyModalDialog show = {this.state.is_showed}/>
        </>
    );
}

// обработать выбор элемента из выпадающего списка
ipc__handleSelect = (eventKey: any, event: any) => {
    this.setState({
        is_showed: true
    });
}
```

но может это топорно все и есть правильный способ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше вообще не рендерить модальное окно, если оно отключено.
Биндим туглер модала -> пробрасываем пропсами в селект и в сам модал для закрытия окна, если он рендерится.

```
this.state.is_showed ? <MyModalDialog /> : null
```

```js
render() {
    return (
        <>
            <Dropdown>
                ...
            </Dropdown>
            {this.state.is_showed ? <MyModalDialog close={/*ф-я изменения стейта для закрытия модала*/} /> : null} // рендерим модал, если он установлен.
        </>
    );
}

// обработать выбор элемента из выпадающего списка
ipc__handleSelect = (eventKey: any, event: any) => {
    this.setState({
        is_showed: true
    });
}
```

Comment: ну да, это я в голове держал, просто в код не стал ставить, меня больше интересовал вопрос куда мне этот элемент пихать - т.е. вся отрисовка должна быть в отрисовке, как я понял - все в `render`?

Comment: Да, если у вас компонент управляется реактом, то он должен быть в рендере.

Comment: а есть какие-то иные варианты?

Comment: На голом JS вставлять/удалять HTML элементы(не компоненты, а именно элементы) в componentDidMount через document.createElement и т.д., но это костыли, которые не могут быть чем-либо обусловлены и влекут за собой ворох проблем.